# How to implement the same for loop in python of corresponding java syntax

Tags: java, python, for-loop

I did this the Prime number check program in Java as follows:

This is more optimized than O(n) due to less comparisons, as it goes only up to the square root of the number. Here I haven't included condition for 1.

```
static boolean isPrime(int number) {
   for(int i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {
       if (number % i == 0) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

I don't know how to implement `i*i <= number` check *in* Python for loop.

This is what is did, it works.

But I want to know if I can do this check like in Java `for` loop without using this explicit `if` *inside* the `for` loop in Python:

```
def is_prime(number):
  # explicit conditions here
  for i in range(2, number+1):
    if i**2 <= number:
      if number % i == 0: return False
  return True
```

Is there any other way to do this directly in `for` like in Java?

Comment: Why don't you run to the square root of the number instead?

Comment: because the library/module functions are not permitted

Comment: You'd actually want `if i**2 > number: break` in the condition, otherwise you'd keep on looping even though you don't check the mod.

Comment: Why does it have to be a 'for' loop? Why not a 'while' loop? (which is trivial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `range(2, number+1)`, you can use `int(number**(0.5)+1)` which is essentially the same as using `i*i<=number` in Java

```py
def isPrime(number):
    for i in range(2, int(number**(0.5)+1)):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Talking more about your code, you can break the loop if value exceeds instead of running all the iteration:

```py
    if i**2 <= number:
      if number % i == 0: return False
```

It can actually be replaced by following:

```py
    if i**2 >= number: break
    if number % i == 0: return False
```

**PS:** `n**0.5` or `n**(1/2)` just means squared root (** means power in python), and you can also use `sqrt` function from math

Comment: thank you, this does the trick, here you are going only till the square root of the number + 1 as its power is 0.5, right?

Comment: @jdk, yeah and I have added a note at the bottom as well

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a loop from 2 to the square root of a number, in python you can do it like so:

```
for i in range(2, int(number ** 0.5) + 1):
    pass
```

If you still want the equivalent condition as the java program, the closest thing in python is a generator:

```
my_gen = ( i for i in range (2, number) if i**2 < number)

for i in my_gen: 
    pass
```

Comment: thank you, this also works, but i know much less about generators.

Comment: I think this generator is just unnecessary, because `range` just works fine for a given upper and lower limit.

Comment: @ThePyGuy yeah I was just trying to replicate the java code exactly.

Comment: @Mohammad, It doesn't replicate the Java code. First thing is, the generator will run for `number` of times since it needs to check `i**2 < number` for each value of `i`. What you have proposed is very inefficient method. Additionally, it needs two for loops, the first one for the generator itself, and the second one is for iterating the items in the generator, and this is more inefficient than what OP already has in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate to the square root of the number only, that will eliminate the need to do this >  `if i**2 <= number`

```py
def is_prime(number):
  for i in range(2, int(number**0.5)):
      if number % i == 0: return False
  return True
```